# How can I report the current tfs user from tf.exe?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

How can I report from my build scripts who the current tfs user is?

I'm setting up automated builds with TFS 2013 and VSO and I'm having workspace errors.
I'm unable to checkout files through the build script.
I'd like to know what the user is running the tf.exe command (I've already had issues with the user running the build being automatically set to a Network Service user, who has not permissions)

Answer (score 1):

In any of the pre-/post-script print the `USERNAME` variable. In Powershell

```
Write-Output "Running as '$env:USERNAME"
```

In a batch file

```
echo Running as %USERNAME%
```